# Smoothing selected parts of mesh

Tags: mesh

I want to keep a few edges of my mesh straight and flat while making other parts of the mesh smooth and curved. How do I do that? I tried using catmull-clark but I can't choose what to subdivide and what not

Comment: This will be a hard question to answer without more information. Ideally, by uploading a copy of your blend file to a hosting site like [Blend exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), or a similar site, and perhaps also uploading one or more screenshots showing what edges you want  to keep flat, and which you want to smooth.

Comment: In edit mode, In the `mesh tools` section of the `tools` tab in the toolbar on the left, there is a `Smooth Vertex` button. Select the vertices you want to smooth and click that button.

Comment: Use `Shift`+`E` to crease edges

Comment: You could make some edges look smooth: select faces, then go to 'mesh' menu (or ctrl+F) then choose 'shade smooth' or 'shade flat'

Answer (score 0):

Add a `Subdivision Surface` modifier and you can select(paint) things you wish with `C` and then press `Shift+E` to make it smooth or edgy.